# Windows 7 Gadgets doesn't appear properly

Tags: windows-7, desktop-gadget

For some reason, Gadgets in my Windows 7 OS stopped displaying properly. Did a little research on internet and found that UAC may be the culprit. However, despite putting UAC on level 2, they still don't appear properly.

I am able to choose and add Gadgets on the desktop, but they won't display properly.

--

My Problem is exactly depicted in this screenshot that I found on the Internet:

[image]

Comment: "won't display _properly_ " - explain that with a bit more detail?

Comment: I mean, if I add clock to the desktop, All I can see is a black background with a green vertical line. Even the other gadgets aren't getting displayed properly. I can show you a screenshot, but I am not sure how to add it here.

Comment: And FYI, I created a new account (for testing) and gadgets appear fine there. But not in the account I use regularly.

Comment: Have you turned UAC off? I've seen a lot of posts from people who have had problems after turning UAC off

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you disable "Windows Gadgets Platform", restart your machine, re-enable it and check if the problem persists.

To do that, go to the `Control Panel`, click the `Programs` heading, and choose `Turn Windows features on or off`. Find the `Windows Gadget Platform` option and remove the check mark from the box to its left, then click the “OK” button.

[image]

Comment: Did both of them earlier, but didn't help :(

Answer (score 1):

Try Re-registering `vbscript.dll` file.

Open an elevated Command Prompt window. by clicking on Start -> All Programs  > Accessories. Right-click Command Prompt, and then click Run as Administrator.

Type the following command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

`regsvr32.exe vbscript.dll`

You should see the following message after running the command:

`DllRegisterServer in vbscript.dll succeeded.`

Close any gadgets and open them again. If that does not help, restart Windows and check.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work.

Comment: Did registering the dll outright fail, or did it register successfully but not solve the problem?

Comment: That fixed this issue for me. Issue caused (I am pretty sure) by installing Visual Studio 2012 Pro ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the windows sidebar folder in your application data folder? Try killing the sidebar process (from the task manager), then go to `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Sidebar` and remove all of the files (or copy them elsewhere to keep a backup). Then, open up the gadgets window from the desktop and try adding gadgets. It should behave the same as if you were adding gadgets to a new account.

Answer (score 0):

> You should delete 1 extra (parasite)
>   zone from
>
> `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
>   Settings\Zones\`
>
> with pseudo-graphic number, you'll see
>   it before zone number 0. It seems this
>   is a bug of Adobe flash player update,
>   though I am not sure.
>
> The pseudo-graphic number is before
>   zone number 0 looks like a miniature
>   upper case "L".
>
> Delete that registry entry and all is
>   well.

(paraphrasing a proposed answer from [Sledge](https://superuser.com/users/55294/sledge) / [Pete](https://superuser.com/users/55201/pete), which got wiped unfortunately)